# Nested If / Then VB Statements in MS Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have worked with several individuals over a whole week who have some VB experience, but we can not get all of these If / Then statements to work correctly.  All work with the exception of the statements that reference "otype" + SCE+ CNE and "otype" = Dedicated Line or Internet Only. The logic appears to be correct, but we do not get the expected results.  HELP!  Below is the VB code where we have questions.  Thank you.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Rem CNE Customer
    If Range("otype") = "SCE+ CNE" Then
        Worksheets("VNC Form").Visible = True
        Worksheets("ISC Portal").Visible = True
        Worksheets("ISC Request Only").Visible = False
        Worksheets("VPN Details").Visible = False

    Else
        Worksheets("VNC Form").Visible = False
        Worksheets("ISC Portal").Visible = False
    End If

    Rem ISM ABC Customer
    If Range("otype") = "SC4ABC" Then
        Worksheets("ISM-ABC Customers").Visible = True
        Worksheets("ISM Portal").Visible = True

    Else
        Worksheets("ISM-ABC Customers").Visible = False
    End If


    Rem VPN Details tab
    If Range("ctype") = "VPN" Then
        Worksheets("VPN Details").Visible = True
        Worksheets("ISC Portal").Visible = True
        Worksheets("VNC Form").Visible = False

    Else
        Worksheets("VPN Details").Visible = False
        Worksheets("ISC Portal").Visible = False
        Worksheets("VNC Form").Visible = False
    End If

    Rem Connections tabs
    If Range("ctype") = "Dedicated Line" Or Range("ctype") = "Internet Only" Then
        Worksheets("ISC Portal").Visible = True
        Worksheets("VPN Details").Visible = False

    Else
        Worksheets("ISC Portal").Visible = False
        Worksheets("VPN Details").Visible = False
    End If

    Rem AT&T and Connection tabs
    If Range("otype") = "SCE+ Reseller" And Range("ctype") = "CNE" Or Range("otype") = "SCE+ Internal" And Range("ctype") = "CNE" Then
        Worksheets("ISC Request Only").Visible = True
        Worksheets("VNC Form").Visible = True
        Worksheets("ISC Portal").Visible = False
        Worksheets("VPN Details").Visible = False

    Else
        Worksheets("ISC Request Only").Visible = False
        Worksheets("VNC Form").Visible = False
        Worksheets("ISC Portal").Visible = True
        Worksheets("VPN Details").Visible = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: are there extra trailing or leading spaces in any of the cells you are testing against? Are the cases the same (for example **Reseller** <> **reseller** <> **RESELLER** ?

Comment: I used a straight edge to review the code to check for additional spaces and make sure the code was "aligned"  Reseller is only in one spot on the code and is an option to be selected from a drop list on one of the fields.

Comment: Are you sure it is `"SCE+ CNE"` and not `"SCE + CNE"` or `"SCE+CNE"` or `"SCE +CNE"`? Perhaps a sample file would help...

Comment: One more observation. You can combine your above code into `Select Case` as well...

Comment: also, have you debugged your code, line by line, with an example, to see why you don't get your expected results?

Comment: I have debugged the code and found that the statement that references otype = SCE+ CNE and the code ("ctype") = "Dedicated Line" Or Range("ctype") = "Internet Only" does not provide the expected results. The other If then statements work as expected. I also checked the spelling and spacing several times for all of the code.  I printed it and reviewed line by line.

Comment: can you open the Debug/Immediate windows (CTRL+G), paste in this `?Range("otype") = "SCE+ CNE"`, and see what the result is after pressing <ENTER>. If the result is False, then you need to paste in this: `?">" & Range("otype").text & "<"` to see what the **exact** contents of the cell are that you are testing (between the angled brackets, obviously!)

Comment: one more thing, double Kudos for using `Rem` - it's a classic that I haven't seen since using Research Machines 380Z Basic at school!

Comment: how are the ranges **otype** and **ctype** set please, are they typed in by the user, or selected from a drop-down, or Validation List? If they are typed in, how can you be sure the user will match the case of your test code?

Comment: otype and ctype are both selected from a dropdown list.

Comment: Both otype and ctype are selected from a drop down list. I also tried the select statements earlier suggested by Siddharth Rout, but that code did not work at all where I only had two statements that would not work with the If/Then approach.

Comment: in my answer below, one part of it is enclosing different conditions in brackets - for example: `If (x=1 and y=2) OR (a=1 and b=2) then ...`

Answer (score 0):

ALthough my code below might help, I suggest using a drop down menu on the QAT, or buttons on the Ribbon to allow the users to decide what sheets to unhide/hide. Your code as it is will run **everytime** any cell in the worksheet is modified.

As Sid suggests, might be worth enclosing your code in a CASE statement to only run if Target= otype or ctype...

maybe try forcing the case, and forcing the spaces to be zero as below:

```
Rem CNE Customer  

If Trim(UCase(replace(Range("otype").TEXT," ",""))) = "SCE+CNE" Then  
    Worksheets("VNC Form").Visible = True
    Worksheets("ISC Portal").Visible = True
    Worksheets("ISC Request Only").Visible = False
    Worksheets("VPN Details").Visible = False

Else
    Worksheets("VNC Form").Visible = False
    Worksheets("ISC Portal").Visible = False
End If

Rem Connections tabs
If (TRIM(UCase(replace(Range("ctype")," ",""))) = "DEDICATEDLINE") Or (TRIM(UCASE(REPLACE(Range("ctype")," ",""))) = "INTERNETONLY") Then
    Worksheets("ISC Portal").Visible = True
    Worksheets("VPN Details").Visible = False

Else
    Worksheets("ISC Portal").Visible = False
    Worksheets("VPN Details").Visible = False
End If

Rem AT&T and Connection tabs
If (TRIM(UCase(replace(Range("otype")," ",""))) = "SCE+RESELLER" And TRIM(UCase(replace(Range("ctype")," ",""))) = "CNE") Or (TRIM(UCase(replace(Range("otype")," ",""))) = "SCE+INTERNAL" And TRIM(UCase(replace(Range("ctype")," ",""))) = "CNE") Then
    Worksheets("ISC Request Only").Visible = True
    Worksheets("VNC Form").Visible = True
    Worksheets("ISC Portal").Visible = False
    Worksheets("VPN Details").Visible = False

Else
    Worksheets("ISC Request Only").Visible = False
    Worksheets("VNC Form").Visible = False
    Worksheets("ISC Portal").Visible = True
    Worksheets("VPN Details").Visible = True
End If
```